# Android application IPC mechanism

Tags: android, ipc, android-ndk

My application uses some native code in external library. This code is "black box" and consumes a lot of memory. Therefore my application starves of memory. Is it any way to run it as an external process with some communication mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Android Services (android.app.Service).

Comment: Services do not run in a separate process, at least not by default.

Comment: Not if you specify `android:process` attribute.